# Watch video files from USB stick on CHS 435HDC cable box

Tags: usb, video

My cable box (Cisco CHS 435HDC) has a USB port on the front, and I'd like to watch a video file from a USB stick and/or external hard drive.  Googling finds a five-year-old Verizon FAQ that says the USB port hasn't been enabled yet, and no more recent information; the cable-box manual doesn't mention the USB port except on the front-panel diagram. So is this a lost cause, or just an obscure task?

N.B.: I'm not a bit sure this goes here, so if it would be better off on a different SE site please advise.

Comment: Its very unlikely the cable box has the capabilties you are looking for.  If you have Verizon has a provider I would contact them to see if its this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

As the FAQ states, the USB port is most likely disabled. From my understanding, these boxes are purchased from a company who makes them for many purposes and companies, and some choose to utilize the USB port, while most don't. Even if it was enabled, it would likely only work for, as an example, a USB to Ethernet adapter.

Comment: The (five years old!) FAQ says that the USB port will be enabled in the future, so I was hoping that it might've been already. .  . but if it had been, I probably would have found something about it.  Rats!

Comment: @Krysta I've read other guides that say the same thing for various set top boxes. Sometimes it happens, most of the time it does not. The only way it would work is if by some chance someone created custom firmware for the box, but that would invalidate any warranty, potentially interfere with your service, etc. The only thing worth trying is updating the set top box, if possible, through the interface.

Comment: Yeah, it's up-to-date.  Thanks though!